# Webpack: 'Cannot find module' issue when using webpack.ignorePlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

In my code, I have an import statement as following:

```
import '../theme/src/fonts/dist/_icons.scss'
```

What I want to realize is, I don't want to import this file when in building state, which means in build phase I want to ignore this statement. So I use `webpack.ignoreplugin`, and my setting is as below:

```
...,
plugins: [
    ...,
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\.\/theme\/src\/fonts\/dist\/_icons\.scss/, /binder$/),
    ....
]
```

Well, in my built out files the `icons.scss` is not imported, which means it's being ignored. But when I open the built out files it has following error:

```
throw new Error("Cannot find module \"../theme/src/fonts/dist/_icons.scss\"")
```

So anything wrong in my using `webpack.ignorePlugin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generate an empty scss file, then I use an alias, `'../theme/src/fonts/dist/_icons.scss': emptyScssfilepath`, so the build will use this empty scss file instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, and found out that's the expected behavior according to the webpack maintainer: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2858.
And you're right, the recommended solution is to use alias.

Answer (score 0):

You kan try it.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: /^\.\.\/theme\/src\/fonts\/dist\/_icons\.scss/
};
```